# How to view remote Git revision on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, git-remote

For deploying to Heroku, I use `git push heroku master`. But how do I see which revision I pushed up to heroku? (I'm often in doubt if I pushed the recent version up)

For those not familiar with it, Heroku's create script generates a remote git repository that you push to. Upon push, the code is deployed magically.

Heroku adds a remote repository to the local one in the form:

```
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

More info in Heroku's manual ["Deploying with Git"](http://docs.heroku.com/git)

Question is: How can I see latest version in Heroku repository?

Comment: Note that the latest version in the Heroku repository is not necessarily the same as the version in production. If you run `heroku releases:rollback`, then the version in production will change, but the Heroku repository will stay absolutely the same. Use `heroku:releases` to see what is in production.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you've just pushed and want to make sure you're up-to-date, then you can just run `git remote show heroku` and you'll see output similar to this:

```
* remote heroku
  Fetch URL: git@heroku.com:XXX.git
  Push  URL: git@heroku.com:XXX.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

That `(up to date)` at the end will be replaced by `(fast forwardable)` if it is not up to date.

Or, if you're wanting to see the full commit log for the heroku remote, the only way I know how is to check it out first.  `git checkout heroku/master` will give you the current commit hash and commit comment: `HEAD is now at <short commit hash>... <commit comment>`, and `git log` will give you the rest of the story.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I was looking for it everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't actually tell you the ref

Comment: is there any way to see the files themselves online like in a github repo ?

Answer (score 129):

The correct answer is actually so simple. You don't need to checkout anything, neither do you have to resort to COMMIT_HASH hacks (which don't work on Cedar stack). All you need to do is: `git ls-remote <remote>`

```
 > git ls-remote heroku
ddaszxcewb585d3a3c00de816a197b14462791a3        HEAD
ddaszxcewb585d3a3c00de816a197b14462791a3        refs/heads/master
```

Comment: so this will show you the version that a particular remote repository is pointed to?

Comment: To take the output of this message and easily see the git commit log and textual diff:

`git ls-remote heroku | awk 'END{print $1}' | xargs git show`

Comment: @BobbyNorton's comment is the straight-to-the-point answer here. Nice.

Comment: Note that this is **NOT THE SAME AS THE VERSION IN PRODUCTION** necessarily. The version in production might be something else, especially if you have just ran a rollback using `heroku releases:rollback`. Use `heroku releases` to see what is in production.

Answer (score 46):

You may now want `heroku releases` and you'll see like 5 commits. a start at least.

Comment: Thanks. This actually shows me what I want to find out (after doing a rollback what is actually running).

Answer (score 25):

what about

```
git log heroku/master
```

Comment: Depending on how you deploy, the `master` branch reference may or may not get updated to the SHA that was deployed.

Answer (score 11):

if you've run into the situation, like i just did, where a co-worker rolled back your heroku app to a release that doesn't show in `heroku releases` because they only keep track of 2 releases... the checkout of heroku/master method won't help, because HEAD is not what is deployed anymore.

the undocumented to the rescue:

```
$ heroku console "ENV['COMMIT_HASH']"
"12abcdef"
```

Comment: that's sweet but is there any way to get the last git commit. i checked the ENV doesn't have any variable i can use for date.

Comment: This doesn't work on Cedar anymore, if there any replacement?

Comment: I get `'heroku console' has been disabled` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/109). I tried `heroku run "ENV['COMMIT_HASH']"` but I get `bash: ENV[COMMIT_HASH]: command not found`. When I use `echo` I get the string `ENV[COMMIT_HASH]`.

Comment: You can access the Rails console on the Cedar stack by running `heroku run console` and you can see what is inside of the `ENV['COMMIT_HASH']` variable by running `heroku run echo $ENV['COMMIT_HASH']` (since it is an environment variable, you need the '$' - much like `echo $PATH`).

Answer (score -1):

heroku is using plain old Git underneath, so..

show the latest 5 commits on current branch:
`git log -5`

show commit history via Git's gui:
`gitk`

view current status (it'll show if you have any uncommited files):
`git status`