# Access to a file or folder on heroku server

Tags: java, git, heroku

When I deploy my application on Heroku server, the server generate an app automatically and I found on my resource a git url. Example: `git@heroku.com:myapp-ss-1338.git`. How can I access this url to view source code or folder via a web browser?

Comment: AFAIK you can't, heroku it's not like github or bitbucket.

Comment: That mean there is no way to see inside a heroku app (without checkout )?

Comment: With a web browser no, but you can do a clone of the repository in Heroku, or if you simply want to know what revision is deployed in Heroku you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281772/how-to-view-remote-git-revision-on-heroku. Also there is an option to run `heroku run bash`, and see the files uploaded to the server (I have never tested it, so I can't assure you that this options it's going to work).

Comment: If my server create a new folder or file, lets say a image uploaded by the client, is there anyway to see what folder? It looks like "heroku run bash" only show what you uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`heroku run bash` is the best way to see what is actually deployed to dynos. As for the git repo you should treat it more like a way to deploy your app (and so therefore ephemeral) than a place to store your code.

There is no way to view what is in that repo from your web browser.

If you want to get at the files in the Heroku repo you can do so by doing a `git clone [repo address]`.

Comment: For me, the command: `heroku git:clone -a myapp` worked where myapp is the name of the app you are trying to access.

Comment: can't we access this heroku application code using gitweb or what if we have control of heroku's source code is it possible in this situation, may be we can create some plugin to view the source code over browser, I'm new into this please put a light hear

Answer (score 2):

If necessary, you might be able to clone your app’s source from its Heroku Git repository using the heroku git:clone command:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

Replace myapp with the name of your app.

This command creates a copy of the Heroku-hosted repository that contains your app’s source and complete repository history. It also includes a heroku Git remote to simplify future pushes.