# How to access the git repository of heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, repository

I have a project on Heroku and when I type:

```
$ git remote -v
```

I get the following answer:

```
origin  https://git.heroku.com/cliente-mws-usp.git (fetch)
origin  https://git.heroku.com/cliente-mws-usp.git (push)
```

Is there any way to access my git repository from heroku and see my code that is there?

Comment: I dont understood what you want to do. Please, more detalhes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to a file or folder on heroku server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757023/access-to-a-file-or-folder-on-heroku-server)