# Git push heroku master doesn't push any changes in my codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

When I added a gem to my app's `Gemfile`, committed the changes, and attempted to `git push heroku master`, it simply told me all the changes were up-to-date, via the message below.

```
$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
```

How can I go about diagnosing this problem? thank you.

Comment: Did you commit your Gemfile.lock after running bundle install locally after modifying the Gemfile?

Comment: Yes! I did commit my Gemfile.lock and Gemfile after running bundle install locally. Again, it seems restarting my computer helped (I had just installed the heroku cli toolset). Weird!

Comment: Wait, does heroku only look on the master branch to determine if there's changes? I created a separate `heroku` branch to install and push heroku.

Comment: did you `git add .`

Comment: Yes I did actually. I usually use `git add --all`

Comment: can you check that it really does not have the commited code already? Follow the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8035499/2981429

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following:

`git push heroku heroku:master`